# Docker container exits immediately

Tags: linux, docker, lxc

I'm using docker v1.2 and having some issues starting a container. The container exits after the "docker run". What's the best way to troubleshoot such issues? Also are there major differences in running containers under AUFS and BTRFS?

Comment: what are you trying to run? Usually, when the command finishes, the container does it fact exit as well.

Comment: No the problem here is it doesn't run the command, it just abruptly exits.

Comment: docker run -i -t <image> bash

Answer (score 79, accepted):

You can run `docker logs <container_name>` to retrieve the logs

(if you don't know what was the container name, you can run `docker ps -a` to display all the containers)

Comment: this was a perfect idea! thank you. I'm new to docker and I didn't know I could use logs command to debug containers so easily

Comment: This helped me address my issue. Once I viewed the logs, I could see that the container didn't have enough memory to run Java.

Comment: @theelee if `docker logs` doesn't show anything, it means there was no output. Using the `docker ps -a` command, you can see with which status code your container exited (`STATUS` column)

Comment: That just gives me `[dumb-init] -p: No such file or directory`

Comment: @mLstudent33 That's your error. Check your Docker command (CMD) and your ENTRYPOINT.

Answer (score 19):

Make sure you have the `-ti` flags in your `docker run` command, otherwise the docker container will exit without letting you run any shells.

Comment: That does not work when I have `-dti` as flags.

Answer (score 1):

Get this example as a base.

```
docker pull node
docker run -it node bash
```

That way -it means interactive and bash means that you'll access to run scripts inside a complete node container with: yarn, npm, and other features...

Comment: I had problem running docker container to run a piece of code and tested many suggestions for it without any improvement. This helped me a lot and solved my problem completely. thanks

Answer (score 0):

In my case the sa password was being rejected as too long. I must have fumbled the setting at some point and the text following the setting had become "part of" the password.

Finding that out was an adventure.
My iMac had the defaults - no development tools.
I downloaded:

[bootstrap-4.0.0-alpha.t-dist](https://download.docker.com/kitematic/Kitematic-Mac.zip)

[Kitematic-Mac]

Would a Mac person verify please? I have a feeling there was a third download I needed.

Once I got Kitematic up and running it was easy to see the log and why the start failed from the Settings tab, General, Environment Variables, MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD.

Answer (score -5):

Naive, but try..

sudo service docker stop
and then
sudo service docker start

Then docker run the containers you were trying to.